# Vagrant Command Stopped Working: Command not Found on WIndows

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

I've been trying to fire up vagrant from the Homestead folder on Windows but keeps showing

bash: vagrant: command not found

I suppose it is an issue with configuration of commands on Windows

Please, what can be done about this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I had an issue with the system environment variables.

Go to: System Properties -> Advanced -> Click Environment Variables

Then Click **Path** on the System variables section, Add New and type in 
*C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin* depending on your vagrant path.

Click Ok and you're done!

Comment: This is great! It works for me. Thank you @Samuel Cesc

Comment: I did this but still receive the same error. Please , how can i fix it?

Comment: @Code-Lover Check maybe you might need to restart your terminal for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

## It means that its missing from your System PATH variable.

#### To set again:

1. Click on "**Start Menu**"
2. Search "**Environment Variable**" or "**env**"
3. Click **PATH**
4. **Add New**
5. Paste This **C:\HashiCrop\Vagrant\bin** [Vagrant installation path]

Hope it will solve your problem.