# Vagrant command not found on windows

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to set up laravel homestead but all i'm getting is vagrant command not found after installing it. Found this post [Vagrant Command Stopped Working: Command not Found on WIndows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655038/vagrant-command-stopped-working-command-not-found-on-windows) and did set up my environment variable but still the same.

Comment: how did you install vagrant ? whats you os system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with system environment variables.
Go to: System Properties -> Advanced -> Click Environment Variables

Then Click Path on the System variables section, Add New and type in C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin depending on your vagrant path.