# Vagrant - Bash: Command not found

Tags: vagrant

Looking for some assistance with Vagrant, for what I believe is a Server Variable issue.

I have been trying all weekend to get any kind of Vagrant install up and running. I have followed:
[Laravel Homestead installation guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead), and
[Sitepoint Homestead Vagrant VM guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-get-homestead-vagrant-vm-running/).

I am using the default folders for install. Whatever I do, after installing Vagrant, I am unable to run 'vagrant up' or vagrant init' because the command 'vagrant' cannot be found (bash: vagrant: command not found). I am trying to execute from the folder with Vagrantfile in it, as suggested by Sitepoint.

I found this Stack Overflow article: [Vagrant Command Stopped Working: Command not Found on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655038/vagrant-command-stopped-working-command-not-found-on-windows), but with the current version doesn't work as that bin folder is empty (note that the 'embedded' folder beside it is full, with several 'bin' folders down within the subfolder structure).

I am not familiar enough with Vagrant to know to which folder I should set the server variable, if indeed that is the right answer. It has to be simple, as no sites address this particular issue anywhere.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Win 7, Vagrant 2.1.2, Virtualbox 5.2.14

Comment: does  vagrant --version display the version ?? if not then there is an installation issue

Comment: Nope. Same issue as all the others, command not found.Thanks for that though... Does it matter what folder I run the command from?

Comment: I think you have done a mistake when downloading Vagrant 2.1.2, it does have a bin folder  where did you download it from ?? did you try the official  site https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html ??

Comment: absolutely used vagrantup.com

Comment: So I just checked inside the msi file, using lessmsi. Every single file in the msi package is sent to the embedded folder (or one of its subfolders) as the destination.

Comment: I just downloaded the version 2.1.2 and I can assure you that there is in fact a folder called bin at this location `C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin` i.e. in the installation directory

Comment: I agree.  But what's in it? I have nothing.

Comment: Update: I navigated into my vagrant folders, found an executable called vagrant, and tried to run it.  Again - Bash: Vagrant: Command not found.  Git Bash wouldn't execute a file right in front of it.  Answer to that part is to put ./ in front of the filename.  First issue solved, thanks to this post:

Comment: [Why can't Git Bash Run My Executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805173/why-cant-git-bash-run-my-executable)

Still have path issues, it's searching for Ruby way down in this folder:

C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/4aksidm5.fmu/embedded/mingw32/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Don't run it directly :P and yes the `vagrant.exe` is located in the bin folder ...Anyway now add this .exe file into your env variables like mention here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655038/vagrant-command-stopped-working-command-not-found-on-windows.... now in your cmd type `vagrant -v` ...should work now :)

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, Vagrant v2.1.2 is missing vagrant.exe in the i686.msi file.

There are two parts to this answer.

- In GitBash, run commands with .\ preceeding the filename(ie  .\vagrant up). See earlier comments for the credit for this answer.
- Missing executable has been raised as an issue on Github.  Without the executable, it, of course, was throwing a command not found error. https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10026?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

Thanks for your support Rohit.