# Command 'vagrant' not found

Tags: python-3.x, vagrant, ubuntu-18.04

I am re-installing `vagrant` on my local machine unsuccessfully. Initially, I had `vagrant` downloaded, installed and running well, but decided to uninstall it. My uninstall was as follows:

```
$ rm -rf /opt/vagrant
$ rm -f /usr/bin/vagrant
```

Checking for `vagrant` by running `$ which vagrant`, I could not find it meaning it was successfully uninstalled.

To re-install it, I implement the steps below but I keep getting the message `Command 'vagrant' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install vagrant`:

**Installing a virtualbox**

I install `virtualbox` before installing `vagrant`:

```
$ sudo apt install virtualbox
$ which virtualbox
```

**Installing Vagrant: Option 1**

```
$ sudo apt install vagrant
```

This is the result I get:

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> vagrant is already the newest version (1:2.2.10).
> The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
> augeas-lenses bsdtar cpu-checker cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin db-util db5.3-util dmeventd extlinux fonts-lato hfsplus ibverbs-providers icoutils ipxe-qemu ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms ldmtool
> libafflib0v5 libarchive-tools libaugeas0 libbfio1 libcacard0 libconfig9 libdate-manip-perl libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libewf2 libfdt1 libguestfs-hfsplus libguestfs-perl libguestfs-reiserfs
> libguestfs-tools libguestfs-xfs libguestfs0 libhfsp0 libhivex0 libibverbs1 libintl-perl libintl-xs-perl libiscsi7 libldm-1.0-0 liblvm2app2.2 liblvm2cmd2.02 libnl-route-3-200 librados2 librbd1 librdmacm1
> libruby2.5 libsodium-dev libspice-server1 libstring-shellquote-perl libsys-virt-perl libsystemd0:i386 libtsk13 libudev1:i386 libusbredirparser1 libvirt0 libwin-hivex-perl libxen-4.9 libxenstore3.0
> lsscsi lvm2 msr-tools nfs-kernel-server osinfo-db pkg-config qemu-block-extra qemu-system-common qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils rake ruby ruby-bcrypt-pbkdf ruby-blankslate ruby-builder ruby-childprocess
> ruby-did-you-mean ruby-domain-name ruby-erubis ruby-excon ruby-ffi ruby-fog-core ruby-fog-json ruby-fog-libvirt ruby-fog-xml ruby-formatador ruby-http-cookie ruby-i18n ruby-json ruby-libvirt ruby-listen
> ruby-log4r ruby-mime-types ruby-mime-types-data ruby-minitest ruby-multi-json ruby-net-scp ruby-net-sftp ruby-net-ssh ruby-net-telnet ruby-netrc ruby-nokogiri ruby-oj ruby-pkg-config ruby-power-assert
> ruby-rb-inotify ruby-rbnacl ruby-rest-client ruby-sqlite3 ruby-test-unit ruby-unf ruby-unf-ext ruby2.5 rubygems-integration scrub seabios sgabios sleuthkit supermin vagrant-libvirt zerofree
> Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 105 not upgraded.

To check whether `vagrant` has been installed, I run:

```
$ vagrant --version
```

And the result is:

> Command 'vagrant' not found, but can be installed with:
> sudo apt install vagrant

**Installing Vagrant: Option 2:**

I first checked for the latest version of `vagrant` on the [vagrants downloads page](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html), then downloaded and installed it by running these commands:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ curl -O https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.10/vagrant_2.2.10_x86_64.deb
$ sudo apt install ./vagrant_2.2.10_x86_64.deb
```

The result I get is the same as that of option 1 above. I have checked online for similar problems and their possible solutions like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51231696/vagrant-bash-command-not-found) and most suggestions point to the `PATH`. However, nothing is forthcoming.

I have reviewed the [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/index) among other articles on how to properly install `vagrant` such as [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-vagrant-on-ubuntu-18-04/) but the `Command 'vagrant' not found` still persists. What could be the issue? At this point, moving forward with using `vagrant` is completely stalled.

I can tell that `vagrant` is not installed when I run:

```
$ which vagrant
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you just removed the files instead of using `apt-get` or `dpkg` to uninstall the package, the package management is not aware of your manual removal, and so `apt-get` and `dpkg` still think the newest version is already installed, and so do nothing.

`apt-get --reinstall install vagrant`

should solve this.

Comment: This also worked:

`sudo apt remove vagrant` to remove vagrant
`sudo apt install ./vagrant_2.2.x_x86_64.deb` to re-install it